# visual studio - how to show svn annotations?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

How can I check at which revesion certain line of code was introduced?
Ideally I want to have something like that:
[eclipse annotations](http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/Burnette_eclipse_annotate_version_400.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if VisualSVN has something built-in to Visual Studio, but TortoiseSVN (which VisualSVN depends upon) can show that via its "blame" functionality.  See:
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-blame.html#tsvn-dug-blame-simple